# python, regex to find anchor link html

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex in python to find a links html in a larger set of html.

so if I have:

```
<ul class="something">
<li id="li_id">
<a href="#" title="myurl">URL Text</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I would get back:

```
<a href="#" title="myurl">URL Text</a>
```

I'd like to do it with a regex and not beautifulsoup or something similar to that.  Does anyone have a snippet laying around I could use for this?

Thanks

Comment: "I'd like to do it with a regex and not beautifulsoup or something similar to that."  Enjoy pounding that screw with a hammer.

Comment: Seriously: **DON'T** use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Just don't.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Why would you like to do it with a regex and not beautifulsoup or something similar to that?

Comment: @OP, yes you can use regex, if your task is simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Soup is good for you:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''<ul class="something">
... <li id="li_id">
... <a href="#" title="myurl">URL Text</a>
... </li>
... </ul>''')
```

There are many arguments you can pass to the `findAll` method; more [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html).  The one line below will get you started by returning a list of all links matching some conditions.

```
>>> soup.findAll(href='#', title='myurl')
[<a href="#" title="myurl">URL Text</a>]
```

Edit: based on OP's comment, added info included:

So let's say you're interested in only tags within list elements of a certain class `<li class="li_class">`.  You could do something like this:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''<li class="li_class">
    <a href="#" title="myurl">URL Text</a>
    <a href="#" title="myurl2">URL Text2</a></li><li class="foo">
    <a href="#" title="myurl3">URL Text3</a></li>''') # just some sample html

>>> for elem in soup.findAll("li", "li_class"):
...   pprint(elem.findAll('a')) # requires `from pprint import pprint`
... 
[<a href="#" title="myurl">URL Text</a>,
 <a href="#" title="myurl2">URL Text2</a>]
```

Soup recipe:

1. Download the one file required.
2. Place dl'd file in site-packages dir or similar.
3. Enjoy your soup.

Comment: Ok, lets say I only want to only find the a tags that are inside of <li class="li_class">.  So, if the li tag doesn't have that class I don't want to return the a tag.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

you really shouldn't use regexes to parse html.. ever.

try beautifulsoup or lxml.

but... you asked.
so a quick and naive version might look like this:

```
import re

html = """
<ul class="something">
<li id="li_id">
<a href="#" title="myurl">URL Text</a>
</li>
</ul>
"""

m = re.search('(<a .*>)', html)
if m:
    print m.group(1)
```

I can think of a lot of ways this would break.

Comment: Considering what he wants to get back, you probably want something more like `/(<a .*?</a>)/`. And yes, it breaks on pretty much everything.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this since your requirement is simple. No need BeautifulSoup or regex

```
>>> s="""
... <ul class="something">
... <li id="li_id">
... <a href="#" title="myurl">URL Text</a>
... </li>
... </ul>
... """
>>> for item in s.split("</a>"):
...    if "<a href=" in item :
...        print item [ item.find("<a href=") : ] + "</a>"
...
<a href="#" title="myurl">URL Text</a>
```

You can include a check of `'<li class="li_class">'` in the if statement as desired.

Comment: And of course lots of perfectly correct ways to write that HTML (even just switching the title and href attributes, for example!) will make this go down in flames.  What a perfectly terrible "solution"!

Comment: I think you all should not jump too far ahead. What OP wants to do is supposedly very simple. You guys make it too complicated!