# What's the easiest way to extract the links on a web page using python without BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python

I'm using cygwin and do not have BeautifulSoup installed.

Comment: How about installing BeatifulSoup then?  Might be the easiest way :)

Comment: Possibly, I just saw something in my search results that suggested it might be difficult on cygwin, possibly more difficult than doing it without BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Actually, I just installed it pretty easily. It's good to know the other ways though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Getting the value of href attributes in all <a> tags on a html file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671323/getting-the-value-of-href-attributes-in-all-a-tags-on-a-html-file-with-python)

[python, regex to find anchor link html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106597/python-regex-to-find-anchor-link-html)

[Regular expression to extract URL from an HTML link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499345/regular-expression-to-extract-url-from-an-html-link)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care much about performance you can use regular expressions:

```
import re
linkre = re.compile(r"""href=["']([^"']+)["']""")
links = linkre.findall(your_html)
```

If you just want links like in http:// links then change the expression to:

```
linkre = re.compile(r"""href=["']http:([^"']+)["']""")
```

Or you can put "' as optional if by some chance you have html without them around the links.

Comment: Regular expressions would likely actually be faster than doing proper HTML parsing, so I don't think this is a matter of performance but rather correctness.